# Drupal: Node Comments Paging displaying same 10 results

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-comments

```
<?php
    $id = $node->nid;
     $node = node_load($id);
    $node_view = node_view($node);
    $node_view['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
    print drupal_render($node_view);
?>
```

I have above code to print my node comments on my page--*contenttype.tpl.php*

And I have set the comments per page to 10.

But it is displaying the same 10 comments on second page too.
And my url changes perfectly. *?page=1* etc

Can anyone help me out?